# When react component opens for the first time, it sees the js file. it doesn't see when it opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, import, require

I call the javascript codes I wrote in another file to the component I made with React. My javascript file is called when the component is first displayed. but another time when I enter the component, the javascript file is not called. please help me.

component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './TeknikOzellikler.css';
import './TeknikOzelliklerJs.js';

const TeknikOzellikler = () => {

    return (
         <div className="container">
    </div>
        )
}

export default TeknikOzellikler
```

js file:

```
import $ from "jquery";

 alert("open");//I put it for testing. The component is running when it is first displayed. I open another page. Then I open the same page again. then the alert doesn't work. which means my js file only works when the page is first rendered. does not work when viewed at other times.

$(function () {


    $("#urunAciklamasiIcerik").show();

    $("#urunAciklamasi, #urunAciklamasi > a").css({

        "background-color": "white",
        "color": "rgb(255, 123, 0)",
        "border-top": "1px solid rgb(255, 123, 0)"

    });

    $("#teknikOzellikler").css({

        "border-right": "1px solid white",
        "border-left": "1px solid white"


    });

    $("#urunAciklamasi").click(function () {

        $("#teknikOzelliklerIcerik").hide();
        $("#taksitSecenekleriIcerik").hide();
        $("#urunAciklamasiIcerik").show();

        $("#urunAciklamasi, #urunAciklamasi > a").css({

            "background-color": "white",
            "color": "rgb(255, 123, 0)",
            "border-top": "1px solid rgb(255, 123, 0)"

        });

        $("#teknikOzellikler, #teknikOzellikler > a, #taksitSecenekleri, #taksitSecenekleri > a").css({

            "background-color": "rgb(163, 155, 139)",
            "color": "#fff",
            "border-top": "0"

        });

    });

    $("#teknikOzellikler").click(function () {

        $("#urunAciklamasiIcerik").hide();
        $("#taksitSecenekleriIcerik").hide();
        $("#teknikOzelliklerIcerik").show();

        $("#teknikOzellikler, #teknikOzellikler > a").css({

            "background-color": "white",
            "color": "rgb(255, 123, 0)",
            "border-top": "1px solid rgb(255, 123, 0)"

        });

        $("#urunAciklamasi, #urunAciklamasi > a, #taksitSecenekleri, #taksitSecenekleri > a").css({

            "background-color": "rgb(163, 155, 139)",
            "color": "#fff",
            "border-top": "0"

        });

    });

    $("#taksitSecenekleri").click(function () {

        $("#urunAciklamasiIcerik").hide();
        $("#teknikOzelliklerIcerik").hide();
        $("#taksitSecenekleriIcerik").show();

        $("#taksitSecenekleri, #taksitSecenekleri > a").css({

            "background-color": "white",
            "color": "rgb(255, 123, 0)",
            "border-top": "1px solid rgb(255, 123, 0)"

        });

        $("#teknikOzellikler, #teknikOzellikler > a, #urunAciklamasi, #urunAciklamasi > a").css({

            "background-color": "rgb(163, 155, 139)",
            "color": "#fff",
            "border-top": "0"

        });

    });

});
```

I put the alert for testing. The component works when it is first displayed. I open another page. Then I open the same page again. then the alert doesn't work. this means my js file only runs when the page is first rendered. does not work when displayed at other times.

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery with React. React has its own way of getting information from/updating the DOM using state. You may need to revisit [the initial official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: @Andy Even if I just write javascript code, it doesn't see it. you see when the first page is opened. does not see it on subsequent page openings. For example, I experienced the same in the alert code.

Comment: @maria code at the top level of a module (ie, the js file) is only going to run when that module loads, and it will only load once. When do you want the code to run? Every time a `<TeknikOzellikler/>` mounts?

Comment: @maria my point is that React is a JS library that's used to create UI components, and it won't work properly with jQuery. It's a state-managed system that requires you to think a little differently about how UI components are updated and rendered. You may need to start from the beginning and learn more how about React works first.

Comment: @NicholasTower yes. but I tried with useEffect. it still didn't. maybe i wrote it wrong. how should I do?

Comment: `useEffect` is correct, but you will need to put the code in the effect, or have a function that you can call from the effect. You can't reload the js file.

Comment: @NicholasTower I wrote a function in component. I called the function in useEffect and it happened. I solved the problem. thanks anyway